# Supersized JQuery plugin height

Tags: jquery

I have used supersized jquery plugin on my web, but now I want to do footer and under the footer I have got some free place and I don't know, how to fix it. I don't want to have this pixels under the footer, footer should have the last section of the web. Could some one help me? The web page is [here](http://metalista.cz/dotaz/informace.html). The free place is under the green footer and I don't know, how to delete it.

Comment: I went to the web page and I got this error: `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /dotaz/informace.html on this server.`. Can you post any of the relevant code that you've written here?

Comment: It is caused probably by editing files by Git. I have to find out, how enable you to see the web page content.

Comment: It would be easier to just copy and paste the relevant code onto this page so that Stack Overflow users can help you with this problem. (You can add the relevant code using the "edit" button on this page).